# Can Selenium be used to testing single page JavaScript apps?

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium

UI testing beginner here, can Selenium be used for UI testing single page JavaScript apps?

Apps use async AJAX / Web Socket requests, service end points are tested but I need UI testing as well.

Apart from Selenium, which other tools would you recommend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's perfectly fine for pages that are heavy on the ajax, you just may have to do some fine-grained adjusting of the timeouts for each method you call since there won't necessarily be an obvious signal to Selenium when an ajax method completes (like there is when a page finishes loading).

checkout timeout usage here:

http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html

Comment: The problem is that this is not reliable. How long should the timeout be? What happens if the test machine is loaded and it takes longer than usual? "clickAndWait" has very clearly defined behavior, it simply waits until the new page is loaded. I'd prefer if there was some kind of "clickAndWaitUntilGlobalFinishFunctionCalled". A page could simple try to call window["continueTesting"]. If it wasn't a testing environment the function wouldn't exist and no harm would be done. Is something like that available?

Comment: I may be interpreting your question wrong, but if you have a js method that fires when the page has completed all outstanding ajax requests (is this what you mean by GlobalFinishFunction?), you could have that method change an element in the DOM in some pre-determined way and use an explicit wait, such as in the example under the link, to find the changed element.

Comment: OK, thanks! Yes, that is what I meant. If using an element is the best way, I suppose I can live with that. :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It can be used to do that.
If allows you to simulate button clicks and wait for results to load.

You should face no trouble with a single page app.

It has tools that you record your steps and make test cases. Give that a try. Should be very easy even for a beginner.